QUERY IMPORT does not import prime numbers Google Sheet
I want to import from different tables, but Google deletes prime numbers 10, but leaves formulas =5+5. How do I get all the data?
enter image description here
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("link1" ; "'1 Квітень'!W:X");IMPORTRANGE("link2" ; "'Квітень'!W:X");IMPORTRANGE("link3" ; "'Квітень'!W:X")};"Select *")
enter image description here
I don't know much about this, but I've already read a lot of articles and nothing helped. simply imports numerically via IMPORTTRANGE. Also, I noticed that when I put a format on numbers, it appears and then disappears. If possible, write a corrected formula. Thanks


You may try:
=let(Σ;vstack(importrange("link 1";"'1 Квітень'!W:X");
              importrange("link 2";"'Квітень'!W2:X");
              importrange("link 3";"'Квітень'!W2:X")
             );
  filter(Σ;byrow(Σ;lambda(x;counta(x)))))


Thank you very much!!! My friend, all the best to you
